# Multiple tables in select statement to get single column

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

This is academic question. I am using sql workbench.

In sql, when we write,

```
select city.name from city;
```

the execution is faster and result shows all city names.

But, if I write,

```
select city.name from city, country;
```

the execution time is much more and the result shows just one city name over and over.

Why does the extra table name in 'from' part mangles the result? Shouldn't it be ignored totally?

Comment: Read about JOINs. (You're doing an implicit cross join...)

Comment: Or in this case use a WHERE clause to join the 2 tables using a Foreign Key. Decades ago before JOINS this is how it was done.

Comment: Never use that syntax.  It's legacy and was replaced in the ANSI 92 standard (nearly quarter of a century ago).  `table1, table2` is the same as `table1 CROSS JOIN table2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a cartesian product. Probably the query is not returning one and the same name over and over, it is just returning each city once for each row in the country table.

Answer (score 0):

since there are no JOINs , basically you are getting a [Cartesian Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIvx8.png) as a result of the lack of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display data from another table that is connected (in some way) to your first table, try something like this:

```
select city.name, country.name
from city, country
where city.country_id = country.country_id
```

or you can write it like this:

```
select city.name, country.name
from city
join country on (city.country_id = country.country_id)
```

If this is hard to understand I would try look up and read about 'sql join' on google :)